# Mail body does not decode on iOS

Tags: email, smtp, encode

I am trying to send emails using plain SMTP. The mail might contain an attachment so I'm sending it as multipart/mixed. This is, what I am sending:

```
Date: 08 Dec 20 07:49:00 +0100
From: "" <sender@somedomain.com>
To: my.address@somedomain.com
X-Priority: 3
Subject: =?WINDOWS-1252?Q?T=E4st?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="AABCDEFBBCCC0123456789DE"

--AABCDEFBBCCC0123456789DE
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


=E4=F6=FC$=80 dfg
--AABCDEFBBCCC0123456789DE--
.
```

The message should display as "äöü $€".

The problem now is, that every device I checked (Outlook, Gmail, Android) displays the Umlaute correctly. Only iOS does not decode the quoted-printable stuff. It displays the content nicely at the overview but fails when opening the mail.

Any ideas? Is there something wrong with my syntax? I already tried to use UTF8 and base64 encoding and all combinations, always the same result.

Thanks for help
Marco